# How to find these "breaking" points on an offseted curve?

Tags: differential-geometry

Check the picture:
[image: offset curves]

I noticed that for big offset values the offseted curves often "breaks" like this (one or more times).
So my question is that what is that point marked with ':-(', and how can I find it for a given curve and a given offset value (numerically or analytically).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those breaks occur at "focal points", where the "normal lines" to nearby points on the original curve all intersect. For a circle, with outward pointing normals, there's just one of these --- at the center of the circle (i.e., offset by $-r$, where $r$ is the radius).

In general, assuming your curve is given parametrically as $t \mapsto x(t), y(t)$, you can compute the curvature at each point $t$ via
$$
\kappa(t) = \frac{x'(t) y''(t) - y'(t) x''(t)}{(x'(t)^2 + y'(t)^2)^\frac{3}{2}}
$$
The inverse of this is called the "Radius of curvature", 
$$
R(t) = \frac{1}{\kappa(t)}.
$$

In general, if you compute $R(t)$ for every point of the curve, you can offset the curve by any value $s$ that's less than $R(t)$ for all $t$; when you offset by an amount equal to the radius of curvature at some point, you tend to get a "break" at the resulting focal point.